# ALERT_BOOT_COMPLETED not getting received in some phones but works well otherwise

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public class AlertBootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private PackageManager pm;
    private boolean isStoredExternally;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        pm = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            ApplicationInfo ai = pi.applicationInfo;
            isStoredExternally = (ai.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // do something
        }
        if (arg1.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

            if (!isStoredExternally) {
                // I start a service here
            }
        }
        if (arg1.getAction().equals(
                Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE)
                && isStoredExternally) {

            // I start a service here ..
        }

    }

}
```

I am starting a service from my BroadCastReceiver by receiving ALERT_BOOT_COMPLETED. This code is working for me in some phones like Samsung SII but is not working on other phones like the Sony Xperia Neo.. Anyone please tell me what to do here. I am kind of stuck..

Comment: I have added all permissions in manifest and intent-filter actions in my receiver...

Answer (score 1):

It might the case that the working device is pre 3.1 . If I remember correctly, after 3.1 the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast is handled only after the first time the user opens the application.

Check [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html).

Comment: I am using these two in my receiver's intent-filter:: android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED and android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE. Also, the code is working for Samsung SII which has v4.0.1 but not working for Sony xperio NEO which has v4.0.4 and another device which is v2.3.5... I am even more confused now.. Please help!!

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you mean

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's not the issue I was pointing out. Sorry I could not help :-(